# Поменять элементы списка местами

Tags: css, jquery, css3, list

Хочу сделать так, чтобы элементы сложного списка, выводящиеся при помощи CSS в виде таблицы, менялись местами. Общая идея показана [image: на картинке по ссылке]
<sub>(источник: [khvorostin.com](http://i.khvorostin.com/img/example.PNG))</sub>
.

Упрощенный CSS:

```
#menu ul {
display: table-row
}

#menu ul li {
display: table-cell;
}

#menu ul li ul {
display: table-row;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Уровень1 (элемент 1)
  <ul>
    <li>Уровень 2 (элемент 1)</li>
    <li>Уровень 2 (элемент 2)</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Уровень1 (элемент 2)
  <ul>
    <li>Уровень 2 (элемент 3)</li>
    <li>Уровень 2 (элемент 4)</li>
  </ul>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы по возможности обойтись силами CSS.
То же самое на [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/quNaU/)

Comment: опишите результат разметкой, а то на картинке идея уж сильно общая

Comment: Уровень 1 выполняет роль шапки для элементов уровня 2. Нужно, чтобы уровень 1 оказался ПОД уровнем 2.

Comment: Прекрасно. Именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на и поменяйте местами уровни.

```
<li>
  <ul>
    <li>Уровень 2 (элемент 3)</li>
    <li>Уровень 2 (элемент 4)</li>
  </ul>
  Уровень1 (элемент 2)
</li>
```